# what is the best OCR document classification ML algorithm?

Tags: elasticsearch, machine-learning, ocr, elasticsearch-mapping

I have developed an OCR module that extracts scanned document's content and store it in elasticsearch mappings .Now, I am trying to improve the ocr by telling it to classify the documents by types(diploma , certificates,identity card ) , each type would be stored in a specific index . What is the the best Machine learning algorithm that can get the job done ?

Comment: Did you look at `More Like This Query (MLT Query)` ?